# Java Combining regex values

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out how to combine regex values to do 2 things
1) remove all spaces 
2) remove all punctuation

right now I am using

```
splitWords = (currentLine.split("\\s+"));
```

This removes all the white spaces from the file I am reading in, now how do I add punctuation? According to the API /p removes all punctuation.

Update: 
Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using split because I am splitting a words in a file by spaces and then adding them to an array, so for example: hello how are you in an array turns into : arr[0] = hello, arr[1] how, arr [2]= are.. etc. However I don't want an element in an array to have punctuation.

Comment: In regex `|` acts as an or

Comment: I tried splitWords = (currentLine.split("s | p")); with no luck. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: When you say `/p`, did you mean `\p{Punct}` ?

Comment: yes, sorry, I used the wrong symbol it should be \p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine multiple character classes in a character class:

```
"[\\s\\p{Punct}]+" // Whitespace + Punctuation (POSIX)
```

For the unicode version, use:

```
"[\\s\\pP]+" // Whitespace + Punctuation (Connector,Dash,Open,Close,InitialQuote,FinalQuote,Other)
```

or:

```
"[\\pZ\\pP]+" // Separator (Line,Paragraph,Space) + Punctuation (...)
```

No need to use `split()` if you just want to remove the characters:

```
// Returns "HesaidItsaniceworld"
"He said: \"It's a nice world\".".replaceAll("[\\s\\p{Punct}]+", "");
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using split because I am splitting a words in a file by spaces and then adding them to an array, so for example: hello how are you in an array turns into : arr[0] = hello, arr[1] how, arr [2]= are.. etc. However I don't want an element in an array to have punctuation. However, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace punctuation and white-spaces then why are you using `split` method.

use like this- `currentLine.replaceAll("\\s+|[<punctuation marks>]+", "")`

Where `<punctuation marks>` are all punctuation marks. i.e. `[\\!,\\.\\?]`

Comment: You don't have to escape `!`, `.`. and `?` in a character class (`[]`).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But just to be at safe side, we can escape any char in regex pattern where we are not sure if it has a special meaning or not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using split because I am splitting a words in a file by spaces and then adding them to an array, so for example: hello how are you in an array turns into : arr[0] = hello, arr[1] how, arr [2]= are.. etc. However I don't want an element in an array to have punctuation.

Comment: Then just remove punctuation marks first and then split based upon what spaces boundary.